# InstallUtil error caused by a custom settings provider

Tags: c#, windows-services, installutil

I define `MySettingsProvider` class that is derived from [`LocalFileSettingsProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.configuration.localfilesettingsprovider) and used for storing [apllication settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/application-settings-overview). The settings are used in service [installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.configuration.install.installer) instance. I'm trying to install my service using [InstallUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool):

```
InstallUtil MyService.exe
```

If I place **InstallUtil.exe** file to the same directory as the service, then installation proccess is completed successfully. If I try to call **InstallUtil.exe** via `PATH` environment variable then the following error occurs:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load provider type: MyService.MySettingsProvider, MyService, Version=1.0.7051.29790, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

I tried to define `MySettingsProvider` and `MyService` in different assemblies, but results are same. Why the utility cannot use a custom settings provider class that is defined in same assembly as a service installer? Is it possible to solve the issue without coping **InstallUtil.exe** to installation folder?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to give the full path to InstallUtil

"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe" ServiceName.exe